# Make outgoing call with built-in modem in C#

Tags: c#, phone-call, modem

I have to call phone number and detect if the modem at the opposite side is hang-on.
How can I do this in C# with SerialPort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) is the class to use.

Something like this:

```
// Set the port name, baud rate and other connection parameters you might need
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600 );
port.Open();
port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
port.NewLine = "\r";
port.WriteLine("ATZ"); // reset the modem
port.ReadTo("OK\r\n"); // wait for "OK" from modem
port.WriteLine("ATDT 12345678"); // dial number with dialtone
string response = port.ReadTo("\r").Trim(); // read until first newline
port.Close();
```

It's not tested as I don't have a modem at hand.

Comment: How do you detect a busy signal after the ATDT command with SerialPort?

Comment: It's been a while since I fiddled with modems, but if you use a terminal and dial manually with "ATDT 123456" to a number which responds with a busy signal, do you get any output/response? If so, check for this. You could issue ATX4, to enable detection of both dial tone and busy signal. Google for AT commands for more informtaion on busy detection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a connection in windows that is configured correctly (so you could manually dial it). Then use the RAS API to dial the connection an check the result.